# Why am I not forced to catch Exception here?

Tags: java

Ran across something that's got me puzzled. Why am I not forced to declare "throws Exception" in the method signature here?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("foo");
            // throw new Exception();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Now, if I enable the commented out line, it does force me to declare it which is what I'd expect. I suppose this qualifies more in the Java puzzle category and it's really bugging me that I can't figure it out :)

Comment: I get the compiler error `unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown` even when `throw new Exception();` is commented out.

Comment: @rgettman Java version? Because I don't on 7.

Comment: This is JLS (if not compiler) -dependent.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get that on 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7.

Comment: @rgettman Maybe another IDE feature. There was something similar recently.

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.7, FWIW.

Comment: @rgettman  That's why I included compiler-dependent as a possibility above.  Have you tried with compilers besides JDS's?  IBM's?  JRockIt?  Eclipse's internal compiler?  What about possible "disable/enable smart exception detection" options in them?  It's difficult to do such an analysis for a small behavior like this.

Comment: This feature was added in Java 7 as part of the multicatch feature. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html Compiler correctness is _not_ generally JVM or compiler-dependent, since the JLS is pretty specific about what the language does or doesn't allow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is doing data flow analysis and realizing that the only exceptions that can be thrown in that segment are unchecked.  So, what you re-throw is an unchecked exception which does not require declaration.

Comment: Interesting. I actually stole the example (and morphed to a main()) from an open source tool which was doing some tricks with exception handling and saw this. It had a much more complicated try block, but I guess the flow analysis figured it out.